# Digital Persona 's Simulator

Tags: c#, .net

I have to read data from finger print reader and convert into byte array. I dont have the device to test my application. Is there any simulator to pass some mock data and test the functionality??

Comment: Did you tried anything so far? Show your effort first..

Comment: I have completing my coding for capturing the finger print and converting to byte array. I need to test that